# Merge an object into another by reference

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to merge data from one object to another, which is in an array. I'm currently using a `for` loop to add them, but I was wondering if there was another quicker way, like somehow using the spread operator. Since doing

```
theElement = {...theElement, ...toMerge[key]}
```

would obviously just create a new object rather than update it.

`filtered` is just an example. The array may contain many more elements, and I need to merge based on the key in `toMerge` matching that of the `key` in `filtered`.

```js
let toMerge = {
  1234: {
    example: "example1"
  },
  12345: {
    example: "example2"
  }
}

let filtered = [
  {
    key: "1234"
  },
  {
    key: "12345"
  }
]

for (let key in toMerge)
{
  let theElement = filtered.find( element => element.key == key)

  for (let innerKey in toMerge[key])
  {
    theElement[innerKey] = toMerge[key][innerKey]
  }
}

console.log(filtered)
```

What I'm looking to change is:

```
  for (let innerKey in toMerge[key])
  {
    theElement[innerKey] = toMerge[key][innerKey]
  }
```

Comment: Object.assign() might be an option, but it is not a deep merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use spread syntax here, but you can optimise a lot by just iterating over `filtered` instead enumerating `toMerge` and then accessing the element with `find`. Also you can replace the inner loop with `Object.assign`:

```
for (const theElement of filtered) {
  Object.assign(theElement, toMerge[theElement.key]);
}

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: I've updated my question since I missed out some info. the merging needs to match the keys. `filtered` may be much longer than `toMerge`

Comment: @A.Lau The merging *does* match the keys. It accesses the `toMerge` object with the `theElement.key` property.

Comment: sorry, you are right. `Object.assign` is probably the best here.